# Celery - No matching distribution found after pip update

Tags: python, pip, celery, kombu

I am unable to install celery/kombu. When installing, I get the following error.

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kombu<6.0,>=5.2.3 (from celery) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kombu<6.0,>=5.2.3
```

---

I am using:

- Python: 3.8
- Pip: 23.0.1

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 3.8 is the version

Answer (score 4):

I also got the same error. I am using Python 3.7.9
The error got resolved as I upgraded the pip version and re-installed celery again.